Как выложить телеаграм бота на хостинг?
Вот если у меня есть телеграмм бот как его выложить на хостинг? Смогу ли я потом редактировать код бота?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Без Ansible не получится

Тут все просто. Находишь метод подключения, типа Telnet, SSH и копируешь репозиторий на удаленный, и оттуда на хостинг. (Но если у тебя один файл, можешь открыть через Vim, Nano и просто вставить).
И дальше просто закинь команду python main.py (для примера) в автозагрузку.
Изменять можно будет через Vim, Nano.
